Why did the Teshuvos Avnei Yashfei quote Rav Elyashiv anonymously?
Rav Yisrael Pesach Feinhandler, author of the Teshuvos Avnei Yashfei, often quotes the psak halacha of a "Gaon Echad" who was eventually revealed to be Rav Elyashiv.
Why didn't he write in the teshuvos that it was Rav Elyashiv? (If it was Rav Elyashiv's preference to be anonymous, why was it ultimately revealed?)

Rav Feinhandler himself publicized in his introduction of the FIRST volume of Shut Avnei Yashfei, his thanks to "Gaon Echad", Rav Elyashiv, and that his rulings were included in the sefer. In subsequent volumes, he continued to thank Rav Elyashiv for answering his queries.
Why didn't he write in the teshuvos that it was Rav Elyashiv?
I suspect that it had to do with certain Yerushalmi politics...
